# Wordpress Posts on Static Pages

Tags: static-website

We're struggling to get posts to show within a static footer section within Wordpress. The footer is static HTML/PHP Code. We've  used the below code to show the latest post with static .php pages throughout the site, but within Wordpress it's refusing to load. Does the code need tweaking?

```
  define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); 
  require('blog/wp-load.php'); 
  query_posts('posts_per_page=1');
  ?>

<div id="blogFeed">
<?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <p class="moreNews darkGrey"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank">Read more...</a></p>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

The static webpage is https://www.had-print.co.uk

The Wordpress link is https://www.had-print.co.uk/blog

I know this is going to be something stupid, but we can't work it out.

Thanks

Andy

Comment: Instead of using WP code outside of a WordPress instance, have you considered using the [official API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/) to fetch these posts?

Comment: Use a standard `WP_Query()` within WordPress, the method you're using here conflicts with WordPress because of redundancies. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/